# A basic question on complete intersection liaisons of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, hilbert-schemes, linkage

I am a beginner in the Linkage theory and would like to clarify certain points I am not sure of.
Let $P$ be the Hilbert polynomial of a curve in $\mathbb{P}^3$. Let $L$ be an irreducible component of the Hilbert scheme $\mbox{Hilb}_P$. Assume that a general curve in $C$ is locally complete intersection (l.c.i.) in $\mathbb{P}^3$. Suppose that there is another Hilbert polynomial $Q$ such that a general element in $L$ is linked to an element in an irreducible component of $\mbox{Hilb}_Q$ i.e., for a general l.c.i. curve $C$ corresponding to a point in $L$ there exists a l.c.i. curve $D$ corresponding to a point in $\mbox{Hilb}_Q$ such that $C \cup D$ is a complete intersection curve in $\mathbb{P}^3$. Then,

1) Can we find an irreducible component, say $L'$ of $\mbox{Hilb}_Q$ such that a general element in $L'$ is linked to an element in $L$?

2) If so, and if $L'$ is non-reduced then is $L$ non-reduced?